# Brouwer theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, geometry, algebraic-topology

Is the Brouwer's fixed point theorem true for the topological space '+' sign(cross)? 
$$
+ = \left( [-1,1] \times \{0\} \right) \cup \left( \{0\} \times [-1,1] \right)
$$
I have tried using spencer's coloring lemma and various facts from analysis but it seems that the solution requires methods from algebraic topology which I am not familiar with. Can anyone help?

Comment: what is this '+' space exactly?

Comment: Union of [-1,1] along the x-axis  and the y-axis.

Comment: I've inserted a definition of the + space. Please check if this is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D$ be the closed diamond with vertices $\langle\pm1,0\rangle$ and $\langle0,\pm1\rangle$, and let $P$ be the $+$ space. There is a retraction $r$ of $D$ onto $P$: push the points $\left\langle\pm\frac12,\pm\frac12\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle\pm\frac12,\mp\frac12\right\rangle$ in to the origin. More precisely, if $x,y\ge 0$ and $0\le x+y\le 1$, then

$$r(\langle x,y\rangle)=\begin{cases}
\langle 0,y-x\rangle,&\text{if }x\le y\\
\langle x-y,0\rangle,&\text{if }x>y\;;
\end{cases}$$

this takes care of the first quadrant, and the other three are handled similarly.

Now let $f:P\to P$ be continuous; then $f\circ r:D\to P$ is a continuous map of the compact, convex set $D$ into itself, so by the Brouwer fixed point theorem it has a fixed point, which is clearly also a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Isn't the composition map , a map to a non-convex subset of D rather than itself?

Comment: @LeoEuler: You're very welcome. It's a map of $D$ **into** $D$, which is all that's needed; the theorem doesn't require the map to be **onto** $D$.